# Having issue with year() function

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create a module to pull data from a giant spreadsheet that I have on another sheet by year. Every part of the code works except for the part that matches the year to a user entered year.

Here's how I defined the user input and how I tried to write the if statement.

```
Dim y As variant
y = InputBox("Input year here")

If Year(RptSht.Cells(i, 2)) = y
```

At this point I get a type mismatch (I've tried setting y as an integer instead). Also just as a note I can use

```
Year(RptSht.Cells(i, 2))
```

to get a value, it just mismatches with `y`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Year()` in VBA returns an `Integer` or `Long` type. You are declaring `y As Variant`. Change to `Dim y As Long`.

Comment: Also to note, you should look at error handling WHENEVER you are interacting with users. Namely, when using an `InputBox` how are you checking the information the user inputs is a year?

Comment: What is the format of `RptSht.Cells(i,2)`?  Is it a date, an integer or text?

Comment: Additionally, if you still get `type mismatch` then you need to asses if `RptSht.Cells(i,2) contains dates because `Year()` requires a date.

Comment: @Dean i tried changing y to both an integer and a long and still get the error

Comment: @Gareth Its set as a date, I can get the year() number for anything in the column, it just doesnt want to match with y

Comment: When you get the error, what does `?Year(RptSht.Cells(i,2))` entered in the Immediate window return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> If Year(RptSht.Cells(i,2)) = y
> ```

That's doing too many things. Split it up.

First you want to get the cell at `(i, 2)`:

```
Dim yearCellValue As Variant
yearCellValue = RptSht.Cells(i, 2)
```

Now, we can't just assume that `yearCellValue` is a valid date. We have to *know* it, otherwise if anything is wrong with the assumption, we'll likely run into a *type mismatch* error. Use the `IsDate` function to make sure you're looking at a `Date` value:

```
If IsDate(yearCellValue) Then

End If
```

Inside that conditional block, `Year(yearCellValue)` is safe. Outside of it, it isn't.

```
If IsDate(yearCellValue) Then
    If Year(yearCellValue) = y Then
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Problem is, we don't know that `y` is a valid value either.

```
Dim y As variant
y = InputBox("Input year here")
If Not IsNumeric(y) Then Exit Sub 'bail out, we can't go any further.
```

Comment: I only had 1 cell which was formatted incorrectly at the very start of my data list, but I added the date check to make sure it doesnt break if an order report is incorrectly input in the future

Comment: @gotimm note that [Gary's Student's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57008689/1188513) leverages the `Application.InputBox` function (that's different than `InputBox`, which fully-qualified is `VBA.Interaction.InputBox`) to make sure the user can only enter a numeric value - basically getting the validation for free.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to handle the issue:

```
Sub gotimm()
    Dim y As Long, RptSht As Worksheet, i As Long

    y = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Input year here", Type:=1)
    Set RptSht = ActiveSheet
    i = 1

    With RptSht
        If IsDate(.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            If .Cells(i, 2) = y Then
                MsgBox "match"
            Else
                MsgBox "nomatch"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "no date in cell " & .Cells(i, 2).Address
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ++vaildating `y` is also important.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  **I agree.** Yours is the better answer.

Comment: IDK about that - `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=1` is a neat way to make sure you're getting a valid numeric value IMO - just need to deal with the possible cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that `i` is not assigned or `(i,2)` is not a date. Try this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim y As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    y = InputBox("Input year here")
    i = 5

    If IsDate(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2)) Then
        If Year(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2)) = y Then
             'Logic here
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thus, the `i` is `5` and the reference cell is `B5`. The `IsDate()` checks whether the cell is a date.

Comment: My hunch is that OP stripped it out of their post as "irrelevant", since `.Cells(0, 2)` would be error 1004, not 13.

Comment: Solved the issue, some of the cells are blank and were returning an error which vba tried to compare to y

Comment: @gotimm there are other issues, `y` isn't validated either.